# CXF not adding superclass to generated class

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

I try to add a superclass definition to a generated class based on an incoming XML complexType. When I make the mapping generic, like this, it works:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
  <xjc:superClass name="nl.ilent.bpo.interceptor.Hashable" />
</jaxb:globalBindings>
```

Now I want only one type to subclass this class. I tried many selectors, but this is the only one that finds exactly one type:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/OrganisatieTypes.xsd" node="//xs:complexType[@name='DatumIncompleetType']">
  <xjc:superClass name="nl.ilent.bpo.interceptor.Hashable" />
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Even though many alternatives gave a "0 nodes" result, and this one does not, the generated class does not subclass Hashable. What am I doing wrong?

This is the XSD defining the complexType in ../xsd/OrganisatieTypes.xsd:

```
<xsd:complexType name="DatumIncompleetType">
  <xsd:choice minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:element name="datum" type="xsd:date"/>
    <xsd:element name="jaarMaand" type="xsd:gYearMonth"/>
    <xsd:element name="jaar" type="xsd:gYear"/>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

We are using CXF 2.7.18

Comment: I think your selector should be : node="//xsd:complexType[@name='DatumIncompleetType']"

Comment: Nope, we are using xs prefix: xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/OrganisatieTypes.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='DatumIncompleetType']">
            <xjc:superClass name="nl.ilent.bpo.interceptor.Hashable" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**Edit**

Ok, sorry, that won't work: according to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/vendorCustomizations.html#superclass this is only possible for global bindings, i.e. for all generated classes, not for single generated classes

Comment: Thanks, but no, that doesn't work either. Again, no errors, but no superclass defined in generated class.

Comment: Thnnks for the addition. So it is not possible to add a superclass for a specifically selected type in JAXB. I will accept this answer.